# How to build release apk with netbeans 8.0 and cordova

Tags: cordova, netbeans, release

I'm using netbeans 8.0 and want to build HTML 5 cordova app. 
How to build release apk?

Answer (score 2):

The procedure is explained in this link.

You must edit the netbeans file `nbproject/build.xml` and add this line:

```
        <arg value="--release"/>
```

inside the `<target name="build-android">` tag (be careful, there are more than one `<target>`, put it in the `build-android` one).

The result is something like this:

```
<target name="build-android" depends="create-android,update-plugins">
    <echo level="info" message="${cordova.command} -d build android"/>
    <exec executable="${cordova.command}" resolveexecutable="true" searchpath="true" failonerror="true">
        <env key="${cordova.path.key}" path="${cordova.path.value}:${android.sdk.home}/tools:${android.sdk.home}/platform-tools:${jdk.home}/bin:${ant.home}/bin:${jdk.home}/bin"/>
        <env key="JAVA_HOME" path="${jdk.home}"/>
        <arg value="-d"/>   
        <arg value="build"/>   
        <arg value="android"/>   
        <arg value="--release"/>   
    </exec>
</target>
```

After this, just recompile your project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile your cordova application, on your device or emulator.
then you have to find the folder:
 Documents\NetBeansProjects\Ro\platforms\android\ant-build

inside this folder there is the apk file.